# VBA Code to populate an MI spreadsheet with updates from two different sheets in the same Excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, auto-update

I have three Excel worksheets: Sheet 1, Sheet 2,Sheet 3 all with the same standard data(Column A to E are standard data in all sheets) Columns F to JF are calendar days/Months. The difference being any update to sheet one is a number in a cell  in the calendar corresponding to the Names in Column A while update to Sheet 2 is only a highlight for the applicable cell (cells updated are never the same corresponding cell in Sheet 1 or vice versa - which I think makes sense).

Sheet 3 needs to update for every update(s) to sheet 1 and 2.

I am looking to use VBA to do this update to sheet 3.

Comment: Clarification needed, inter alia: What does Sheet 3 contain? The union of Sheet 1 and Sheet 2? Cat gifs? What do you want to update on Sheet 3?

Comment: Sheet 3 has the same data as Sheets 1 and 2 (no union, all three sheets have the same exact data but the updates will be in numbers for  sheet 1 and in sheet 2 a simple highlight will be applied - but cells updated on sheet one cannot be the same as sheet 2) and every update to sheet  1& 2 should reflect on sheet 3 as well.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the module associated with *Sheet 1*.
The code will copy the modified range as is to *Sheet 3*.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
fr = Target.Row
lr = fr - 1 + Target.Rows.Count
fc = Target.Column
lc = fc - 1 + Target.Columns.Count

For i = fr To lr
    For j = fc To lc
        Sheets("Sheet 3").Cells(i, j).Value2 = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, j).Value2
    Next
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: To do highlight the Sheet 2 contents as well, use `Sheets("Sheet 2").Cells(i, j).Interior.ColorIndex = 37` right after the `Sheets("Sheet 3").Cells(i, j).Value2 = Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(i, j).Value2`.

Comment: Thanks but No changes are effected in sheet 3 when I update sheet 1 or 2